# Optimization problem in Julia - Using array's elements in a contraint

Tags: optimization, julia

I have done the following code in Julia, trying to solve a simple math problem.

```
model = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
@variable(model, x[1:4])
@variable(model, y)
@objective(model, Min, 2*sum(x[i] for i in 1:4) + 5*y +18)
@constraint(model, 5*sum(x[i] for i in 1:4) + y >= 6 )
@constraint(model, (x[i] for i in 1:4) >= 0)
@constraint(model, y >= 2)
@time JuMP.optimize!(model)
```

But when I run the program, I get this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching -(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#143#144"}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
 -(!Matched::Complex{Bool}, ::Real) at complex.jl:307
-(!Matched::Missing, ::Number) at missing.jl:115
-(!Matched::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel, ::Integer) at logging.jl:108
 ...
```

What I'm trying to do on line 6 (`@constraint(model, (x[i] for i in 1:4) >= 0)` is to set a constraint that each, separate element of the array x is greater than zero. For example:

```
x[1]>=0, x[2]>=0, x[3]>=0, x[4]>=0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's reporting an error for `-` there, but the reason is quite simple.

```
julia> (x[i] for i in 1:4)
Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#5#6"}(var"#5#6"(), 1:4)
```

This is a generator, a thing you can iterate over; you can `collect` it into a list (with some dummy `x` for demonstration):

```
julia> x = rand(4);

julia> collect(x[i] for i in 1:4)
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.82205289980846   
 0.1753822661463882 
 0.3134638596396617 
 0.24751968827319581
```

But of course it doesn't make sense to compare a generator to an integer:

```
julia> (x[i] for i in 1:4) >= 0
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#13#14"})
```

What you much rather want is this:

```
julia> collect(x[i] >= 0 for i in 1:4)
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Note that this was using normal Julia.  JUMP uses the same syntax inside a macro and will probably try to stick to the same semantics, but rewrites it the code internally.  Still, comparing a generator to a number does not make sense to it.